# conditional Markov inequality?

Tags: probability

If I have a non-negative random variable $X$, using Markov inequality:
$$P\left(X\geq a\right)\leq\frac{E\left[X\right]}{a}$$
Knowing $E[X]=75$, I can ensure:
$$P\left(X\geq85\right)\leq\frac{15}{17}$$

What I'm having trouble is how does knowing $P(X\geq 61)=1$, let me make the inequality more strict? Specifically, I wish to show: $$P\left(X\geq85\right)\leq\frac{7}{12}$$
But I can't seem to figure out how to use the latter knowledge in order to tighten the ineqaulity. I tried using Chebyshev's inequality but that quite clearly doesn't give me what I wish for. I will be glad for any help/clue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $Y=X-61.$ Then $\operatorname E(Y) = 75-61=14.$ So
$$
\Pr(X\ge85) = \Pr(Y\ge 24) \le \frac{\operatorname E(Y)}{24} = \frac{14}{24}.
$$

Answer (score 2):

Consider the variable $Y = X - 61$. It follows $P(Y \geq 0)= 1$ and $E(Y) = 14$. Now apply Markov to
$$P(X \geq 85) = P(Y \geq 24)$$

Answer (score 0):

My solution.

By the law of total expectation:

$E[X]=E[X|X\ge 85]P(X\ge85)+E[X|61\le X\le 85]P(61\le X\le85)$

Now $P(61\le X\le85)=1-P(X\ge85)$, so that this implies:

$E[X] \ge 85 P(X\ge85)+61(1-P(X\ge85))$

First term is Markov and second a correction using the additional information. With some algebra one gets the result found by other methods.